# Set a RGBA color to a layout

Tags: java, android

I've a Layout which has a bg color customized by user. User fills 4 values.
R-G-B-Alpha

But, I've seen that the method to set the color in a layout, doesnt accept 4 values.
`setBackgroundColor()` just accepts int value.

I've searched for a java parser, from RGBA to HEX but I couldn't find any.

Do you know guys where could I find one?

Thanks.

Comment: you have the 4 int A R G B and you want to retrieve the hex color?

Comment: exactly, thats it. I've something like: a=0.5, r=243, g=200, b=15

Comment: you need the color in rgba or argb is good to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one.

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a_int, r_int, g_int, b_int));
```

Comment: alpha is a value from 0 to 1, so can't be an integer.

Comment: do you thing that doing some maths like `int alpha = float_alpha * 255` would do the trick?

Answer (score 10):

```
int alpha = (int)(a * 255.0f);
Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b);
```

Answer (score -4):

write color code in color.xml in values folder-

```
<resources>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="red">#FFFF0000</color>
<color name="blue">#FF0000FF</color>
```

then in your code set layout background

```
LinearLayout ll=find(...);
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
```

Comment: This does not define the alpha value.