# Remove all Black from RGB to be Transparent

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, rgb, hsv

This is a bit difficult to explain but here goes...

I need a way of getting all the black out of a color so that it acts more like real light.

So for example I want RGB(0, 0, 0) to be Transparent instead of black and RGB(127, 127, 127) to be White at 50% transparency instead of grey.

At the moment I am using this:

```
public static int getHexColor(int[] color) {
    return android.graphics.Color.rgb(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably just keep the colors the same and mess with the alpha channel instead.

Comment: Try RGBA instead of RGB -- http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934796/set-a-rgba-color-to-a-layout

Comment: How would I integrate RGBA to get rid of the black? for instance at RGB(127, 127, 127)  to be white?

Comment: @WillBell if you have two pixels `(25,25,25)` and `(127, 127, 127)` in one picture, should algorithm assume that you have whole picture in `alpha = 50` and first pixel is darker or that first pixel is white with `alpha = 10`?

Comment: @RomanKolomenskii There will only ever be one colour. I am using a box of a single color.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using

```
Color.parseColor("#AARRGGBB");
```

The `AA` is the opacity of the color. So what you can do is get the HEX value of your color, and add one of this opacity values to the beginning of the Hex.

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Credit to @Duggu for the opacity values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

1) Get the maximum of `r`,`g` and `b`. `int max = Math.max(r(Math.max(g,b))`

If `max == 0` skip steps 2 and 3

2) Divide it by `255`: `float alpha = max / 255f;`

3) Scale every value by missing alpha: `r = (int) (r * (1 / alpha))`

4) Create new color `android.graphics.Color.argb(max, r, g, b)`